# SQL Server Returning Strange Dates using CONVERT()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),Enrollment.[Enroll End],106)
```

I thought the above was supposed to return a date like '12 Jan 2016', it is instead returning dates like '15 Oca 2016'. Does anyone know why this is happening? I originally thought maybe the language was set incorrectly but it was not.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx denotes 106 with this

> 1 These style values return nondeterministic results. Includes all (yy) (without century) styles and a subset of (yyyy) (with century) styles.

I'm not sure if the above has something to do with it - though I am not entirely sure what they mean by nondeterministic results

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your international settings would seem to be set to a locale where January is abbreviated as "Oca".  Perhaps Turkish, where "January" is spelled Okac (thanks to http://www.omniglot.com/language/time/months.htm).

Comment: oca is a localised date string, probably turkish

Comment: Could you include your query you are using.

Comment: @AlexK. yes, it is turkish

Comment: What did you do to determine the language was not set incorrectly?

Comment: @TabAlleman I used set language 'us_english' and it still returns the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values returned are non-deterministic because they rely on the locale settings of the user connection. In other words, you can run the same exact code from two different computers and get different results - you can't determine the result based solely on the parameters.

Make sure that your client machine is set to an English locale.

Comment: i used 'set language 'us_english' and it does the same thing

Comment: I think it's my local management studio that is messed up because I just tried from a different client and it returned the correct results

Comment: Are you issuing the `SET LANGUAGE` in the same connection as your `CONVERT`?

Comment: Any idea how/why this would change? I don't remember ever changing this

Comment: Other than going into the settings and changing it manually, not sure.

Comment: A developer who worked here with me changed my setting upon his exit as a prank

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps..
if local setting are different. always use `dateformat`

```
set dateformat dmy

declare @date datetime = '12-01-2016'

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),@date,106)
```